# Porting json response in Ruby to Python

Tags: python, json, ruby, python-3.x, code-conversion

Hey I made a program that takes advantage of a JSON API response in Ruby and I'd like to port it to python, but I don't really know how

JSON response:

```
{
    "Class": {
        "Id": 1948237,
        "family": "nature",
        "Timestamp": 941439
    },
    "Subtitles":    [
      {
        "Id":151398,
        "Content":"Tree",
        "Language":"en"
      },
      {
        "Id":151399,
        "Content":"Bush,
        "Language":"en"
      }
    ]
}
```

And here's the Ruby code:

```
def get_word
    r = HTTParty.get('https://example.com/api/new')
# Check if the request had a valid response.
    if r.code == 200
        json = r.parsed_response
        # Extract the family and timestamp from the API response.
        _, family, timestamp = json["Class"].values

        # Build a proper URL
        image_url = "https://example.com/image/" + family + "/" + timestamp.to_s

        # Combine each line of subtitles into one string, seperated by newlines.
        word = json["Subtitles"].map{|subtitle| subtitle["Content"]}.join("\n")

        return image_url, word
    end
end
```

Anyway I could port this code to Python using requests and maybe json modules?
I tried but failed miserably

Per request; what I've already tried:

```
def get_word():
  r = requests.request('GET', 'https://example.com/api/new')
  if r.status_code == 200:
      # ![DOESN'T WORK]! Extract the family and timestamp from the API 
      json = requests.Response 
      _, family, timestamp = json["Class"].values

      # Build a proper URL
      image_url = "https://example.com/image/" + family + "/" + timestamp

     # Combine each line of subtitles into one string, seperated by newlines.
      word = "\n".join(subtitle["Content"] for subtitle in json["Subtitles"])
      print (image_url + '\n' + word)

get_word()
```

The response and `_, family, timestamp = json["Class"].values` code don't work as I don't know how to port them.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: @SaraTibbetts Yes, no problem! I've edited my post

Comment: This question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670239/extract-data-from-json-api-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `requests` module, you can call `requests.get()` to make a GET call, and then use `json()` to get the JSON response. Also, you shouldn't be using `json` as a variable name if you're importing the `json` module.

Try making the following changes in your function:

```
def get_word():
    r = requests.get("https://example.com/api/new")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # Extract the family and timestamp from the API 
        json_response = r.json()

        # json_response will now be a dictionary that you can simply use

        ...
```

And use the `json_response` dictionary to get anything you need for your variables.